# Typo 3 : Add H-menu first level li to class dynamic

Tags: typo3, menuitem, typoscript

I create menu for my site its working fine but now problem is that i want to add custom class to every li to first level.

My Typo script Below For menu i add class to every li but 2 li class call for all other except first and last. So have idea what need to do for it ?

```
lib.header_top_right = COA
lib.header_top_right {
    10 = HMENU
    10 {
        wrap = <div class="menu-main-container">|</div>
        entryLevel = 0
        1 = TMENU
        1 {
            expAll = 1
            wrap =   <ul id="menu-main-1" class="main-nav">|</ul>
            target = _top
            NO {
                wrapItemAndSub = <li class="home">|</li>|*|<li class="service">|</li>|*|<li class="contact">|</li>|*|<li class="l">|</li>|*|<li class="contact">|</li>
                stdWrap.wrap = <span class="nav-title">|</span><span class="hr">&nbsp;</span>
            }
            ACT < .NO
            ACT = 1

            CUR < .NO
            CUR = 1
            CUR {
                stdWrap.wrap = <span class="nav-title">|</span><span class="hr">&nbsp;</span>
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have three menu items for the first level. "Home", "Service" and "Contact".

Your optionsplit would work like that:

```
wrapItemAndSub = <li class="home">|</li>||<li class="service">|</li>||<li class="contact">|</li>
```

In general you can split the value (wrapItemAndSub in your case) in three parts with: |*|

```
first |*| middle |*| last
```

You could split each part with: ||

```
firstsubpart1 || firstsubpart2 |*| middlesubpart1 ...
```

There are 4 rules to do the split:

1. The priority is: last, first, middle
2. If the middle part is emtpy, the last part of the first is repeated
3. If the first and middle part is empty, the first part of the last gets repeated before the last
4. The middle gets repeated

You can find some examples and this explanation in the [typo3 docs - optionsplit](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ObjectsAndProperties/Index.html#objects-optionsplit)

Although you could reach your goal with the optionsplit, I wouldn't recommend it that way. If your sitestructure is and always will be fix, the optionsplit solution is ok. If your sitestructure changes and an additional link would be added to your first level you would have to change your typoscript for the menu. To "access" each first level menu via css you also could do something like this:

```
wrapItemAndSub= <li class="menu{field:uid}" id="menu{field:uid}">|</li>
wrapItemAndSub.insertData=1
```

The result would be something like:

```
<li class="menu1" id="menu1"><a href="home/">Home</a></li>
<li class="menu2" id="menu2"><a href="service/">Service</a></li>
<li class="menu3" id="menu3"><a href="contact/">Contact</a></li>
```